# Struts2 s:label : Positions of label and value are inverted

Tags: jsp, struts2

In my Struts2 JSP, I want to display an id, so I wrote:

```
<s:label value="Id:">A${id}B</s:label>
```

(`A` and `B` are here for debug)

I would expect it to display as `Id:A7B`
But the following is generated in the HTML: `A7BId:`

Why is the label placed after the value, not before?

If I write `<s:label value="id" name="id" />` then just the following is generated: `id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no Struts2 expert, and the STruts2 documentation is horrible. But a HTML label is just that: a label. It has only one "value": the text of the label:

```
<label>some text</label>
```

So, either user the `value` attribute, or use the tag body. I wouldn't expect a particular order if you use both to set a single value. I would just do it like this:

```
<s:label>Id:A${id}B</s:label>
```

Comment: they have improved a lot recently but on major i am agree :)

Answer (score 2):

That is basically due to the way Struts2 is handling the `<s:label>` tag.It uses Free-marker template internally to handle the rendering the HTML output and here is what it is doing

```
<#if parameters.nameValue??>
<@s.property value="parameters.nameValue"/><#t/>
</#if>
```

So you are passing value as its tag parameters and its extracting that to generate the final output.In you case `value="Id:"` is getting displayed first and den the tag body and hence the output is as per the one you have specified.

in second case its working same as described above.So solution is either use as the value property of tag or make it a part of tag body choice is all yours!!!

Comment: +1 I choose JB's answer because it is simple and fits my need, but thanks for explaining the underlying mechanism!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul:Finally it worked for you that's the best thing :)

Answer (score 0):

For me,

```
<s:label value="Id:%{testBean[#status.index].id}"/>
```

Gives what you wanted. You may modify as per your requirement.

```
<s:label value="Id:A%{id}B"/> will give you what you need.
```